# Get Index of Object Inside Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, indexing

I'm using this https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?limit=10 API to see prices of different cryptocurrencies.

My end goal is to loop through it from top to bottom and get currency titles with corresponding prices. However, it seems I am unable to get an index of an object within the "data" object. I am unable to select it with [], because it is not contained within an array.

If you look at https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?limit=10 , you'll notice that the third item within the "data" object is an object containing information for the Ripple currency.

How can I get this object alone solely from the value of its index?

I'm using jQuery by the way, accessing the API like this:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?limit=10", function(param) {

});
```

Comment: `param.data[52]` would get you ripple, objects can also be indexed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the response is an object containing `data` as another object, you can use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop to iterate through the collection and apply your logic.

Following is a demo of iterating through and printing the names and prices of the currencies.

```js
$.getJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?limit=10", function(response) {
  for (let [_, value] of Object.entries(response.data)) {
    console.log(`Currency: ${value.name}, Price: $${value.quotes.USD.price}`);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Object.values() makes more sense if you aren't using the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the keys of the object then iterate to it, compare the name of the currency.

```js
$.getJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?limit=10", function(param) {
var objkeys = Object.keys(param.data);
objkeys.forEach(function(item){
  if(param.data[item].name==='Ripple'){
    console.log(param.data[item])
  }
})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the object into an array using `Object.values`. To loop thru the array you can use `forEach`

```js
$.getJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?limit=10", function(response) {
  Object.values(response.data).forEach(o => {
    console.log(o.name, o.quotes.USD.price);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

If you want to find a specific `name`, you can use `find`

```js
$.getJSON("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?limit=10", function(response) {
  let toFind = 'Ripple';
  let result = Object.values(response.data).find(o => o.name === toFind);

  console.log(result.name, result.quotes.USD.price);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can parse the JSON response in object using JSON.parse() method. After that iterate through the objects.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse